# Xamarin Forms complexe clickable label

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to create a string that have classic work & linked word.

I have this sentence :

> I accept the **terms of use** and the **privacy policy**

In this sentence I want to have the words in bold clickable.

I already tried with an **Horizontal StackLayout**, **Labels** and **Buttons** but the result do not be like a simple sentence...

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `TapGestureRecognizer` on a label:

```
var terms = new Label() { Text = "terms of use" };
var termsTapped = new TapGestureRecognizer();
termsTapped.Tapped += (o,e) =>
{
    //do something
};
terms.GestureRecognizers.Add(termsTapped);

var stack = new StackLayout()
{
    Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal
};
stack.Children.Add(new Label() { Text = "I accept the " });
stack.Children.Add(terms);
```

... and the same with your **privacy policy**.

**EDIT:**
If you want use this functionallity in a single lable, you could implement your own `Span` which is clickable and work with `FormattedString`.

Comment: ok. I will try with multiple label. If the display is not correct i will implement my own span.

Comment: That's the way to go. ;-) If i could help, please mark as answer.

Comment: I test the implementation mark as answer when it's done :)